# imaplib.error: b'LOGIN failed' when trying to login using imaplib in python

Tags: python, imap, imaplib

Good day, I am trying to use imaplib to connect to exchange server. Below is the code:

```
import imaplib

imap_host = 'example.smth.smth.kz'
mail_login = 'name.lastname@smth.kz'
mail_pass = '**********'


M = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(imap_host)
print(M.welcome)
M.login(user1, imap_pass)
```

M.Welcome returns **b'* OK The Microsoft Exchange IMAP4 service is ready.'**, which means that I was able to connect to the server. However, when I try to log in I got this error:
imaplib.error: b'LOGIN failed'
Altough, credentials are correct. What is the issue here?

Answer (score 1):

Your mail login username and password are incorrect according to your imap4 mail host.

When I look at your code, there is no `user1` and `imap_pass` variable. 
If you want to write your given code correctly it should look like this:

```
import imaplib

imap_host = 'example.smth.smth.kz'
mail_login = 'name.lastname@smth.kz'
mail_pass = '**********'


M = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(imap_host)
print(M.welcome)
M.login(mail_login, mail_pass)
```

Maybe use `getpass` to prevent passwords in your code:

```
import imaplib
import getpass

imap_host = 'example.smth.smth.kz'
mail_login = input("Username: ")
mail_pass = getpass.getpass()

M = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(imap_host)
print(M.welcome)
M.login(mail_login, mail_pass)
```

Comment: 2 years later... I got that error, credentials is ok and was working in the morning. Reset password did not change, logging into OWA works fine, login using imaplib fails with "LOGIN failed" after 1 minute or so!

Comment: @3c71 in the same scenario. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Same issue. Login worked just fine before, but stopped working out of the blue. Webmail login works, but same credentials yield 'LOGIN failed.' when using imaplib.